# Using DataContractResolver in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We are developing workflows in WF4 way. When we use some custom classes we have to add them to knowntypes collection in each send/receive activity to avoid serialization exception. Is there any way we can use DataContractResolver feature which is a new dotnet 4 feature to avoid adding knowntypes ?  Or any alternate solution if any one can suggest ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - check out the sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807504.aspx